# KDE Plasma 5.27.8, Win/Meta button doesn't open the app launcher (Kubuntu 23.10)

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, launcher

Since yesterday (29 february 2024), I've started facing an issue where the Win/Meta button doesn't open the app launcher (or Andromeda Launcher)

I've read that it's supported by Default for KDE Plasma > 5.8, and fair enough, going on a [keyboard test website](https://keyboard-test.space/) does detect the Win button being pressed

I've tried looking for advice online, like the Alt-F1 or Win-F1 shortcuts, but those don't seem to work for my intended use (only pressing the Win button)

Going in keyboard shortcuts, I can't use solely the Win button, it needs another key to be pressed for it to be set...

Did anyone find a solution?

**EDIT:** The problem sometimes comes back but it gets fixed by a system reboot

Comment: You can enable and disable the shortcut in Kubuntu `systemsettings`

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on `Application Menu` icon
2. Click on `Configure Application Luncher` or `Configure Application Dashboard`
3. go to `Keyboard Shortcuts`
4. Set `Meta+A`
5. `Meta` key works solely. Let's try ;)